# Is there a proper way to set the region of MKUserTrackingModeFollow?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

In my code, I'm calling

```
- (IBAction)goToUserLocation:(id)sender {
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
}
```

which then has this callback

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
   // I then try to set the region in here, which doesnt always work.  Sometimes it zooms into the user location, then zooms back out to the region I specify.  Other times, it will just stay zoomed in.
}
```

The MKUserTrackingModeFollow zooms in far more than I would like.  I'd like to be able to set it so that it zooms into a region I specify.  Is there a proper way to do this or is the region of MKUserTrackingModeFollow set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`viewForAnnotation` is completely the wrong place. That is called when ever the map decides it needs to draw an annotation on the map. The map may not need to redraw an annotation if it was already on screen when someone pressed the button to goToUserLocation.

Instead try setting the zoomed out region before the tracking mode is set or after the animation is done.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can set the zoomed out region before the tracking mode, because it requires coordinates to set the region around.  How would I do this after?

Comment: You can set the region before using what ever the current center point is. I've found that when switching on the tracking mode using the tracking mode button it usually pans the map over to my current location and doesn't change the zoom.